# Remote MySQL - Shared host to another host

Tags: mysql, remote-access, dreamhost, bluehost

I have a MySQL database on Bluehost and would like to allow remote access to an application running on a separate server (Dreamhost).  Enabling remote access on Bluehost citing the server IP of the shared server on Dreamhost does not work.  However when I allow my local dev workstation (office IP address) I can connect remotely just fine to the Bluehost MySQL DB.

Why can I not connect remotely from shared server to shared server but I can just fine from my office workstation?  What I am missing here?

Ref: https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/89

Comment: Check whether your database server on Bluehost allowing external connections or not.

Comment: @RavinderReddy Yes, I just need to add the remote IP to allow access - which was done.

Comment: There are few things in allowing access. 1. allow remote clients access in my sql database. 2. open os firewall for such calls from remote clients. If you have enabled them, your remote calls should work